# Keep .gdb structure to postgresql + PostGIS (Feature dataset)

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a .gdb file with a specific structure. I will extract all shp files for uploading to a postgtresql db. But I want to keep the structure of gdb. How can I keep this structure to postGIS+Postgresql? Is it impossible to keep the Feature dataset?

I use Qgis, ArcGIS 10.1, Postgresql and PostGIS 1.5.x

[image]

Comment: You could always run [ArcSDE on PostgreSQL](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000075000000).

Answer (score 4):

There is no concept of a featuredataset in A PostGIS database. This is why you cannot have a 1 is to 1 correspondence between your File Geodatabase and PostGIS database.

The only thing that you could sort of use, is to divide your PostGIS database into different schemas. A schema has almost none of the properties that a featureDataset has (like common Spatial reference, common schema locks etc), but it can be used as a sort of folder for related data. It might also be useful when setting privileges for different types of users.